# Looping through the data frame and match the values from another file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, match

[dput(df) of dataframe2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLMVn.png)

I need some help with r.

I have a data frame:

```
ant <- data.frame(n_scale = c(0.62, 0.29, -0.9), 
                       aa = c('A','B','C'))
```

It looks like this:

```
0.62 A
0.29 B
-0.90 C
```

Then I read a file with a dataframe2 which looks like:

```
-1 0 1 2
C  B A A
```

I want to achieve this:

```
   -1     0     1     2
    C     B     A     A
   -0.9   0.29  0.62  0.62
```

How can I loop through the dataframe2 to get values from the ant data frame?

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: could you provide `dput(df)` for both dataframes?

Comment: Could you please provide the output from `dput` for each of your frames? Two reasons: (1) `-1` is a non-standard column name, usually R changes it to something like `X.1`; (2) letters and numbers in the same "column" means everything is a string.

Comment: Also do you have only one row in `dataframe2` ?

Comment: I have a feeling this is "just a merge/join" (https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272), but somehow dataframe2 is is shown in a transposed state. Perhaps it would be more useful to use it in a columnar format, similar to `ant`?

Comment: You are not going to succeed with a merge unless you first transpose one of the dataframes. Would be easier to use the match function.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I amended the input of dataframe2 as suggested. It is now in a format of what the dput(df) shows above.

Comment: @curious_girl Try `merge(ant, dataframe2)`.

Comment: jay.sf thank you for your suggestion. It works quite good. I get this output:   aa n_scale hyd
1  A    0.62   1
2  A    0.62   2
3  B    0.29   0
4  C   -0.90  -1          Is there a way to keep the original order of -1 0 1 2 while merging the dataframes?

Comment: What you have shared is an image which is of dataframe and not the `dput`. We need something that we can copy/paste into our R session. So image is not helpful here. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `merge`. After that you can `match` `hyd` of result with that of `df2`.

```
res <- merge(ant, df2)
res <- res[match(df2$hyd, res$hyd), ]
res
#   aa n_scale hyd
# 4  C   -0.90  -1
# 3  B    0.29   0
# 1  A    0.62   1
# 2  A    0.62   2
```

Please next time when asking, provide your data as I do below.

---

*Data:*

```
ant <- data.frame(n_scale = c(0.62, 0.29, -0.9), 
                  aa = c('A','B','C'))

df2 <- data.frame(hyd=c(-1, 0, 1, 2),
                  aa=c("C",  "B", "A", "A"))
```